# Закрытый вопрос и награда за него

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

Ребят, я разочарован.

Вот вопрос: [.NET Core 1.0 -- насколько готов к использованию?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542515/net-core-1-0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E)

Вопрос непростой, понимаю. Я и не ожидал что прибегут 10 человек и перебивая друг друга расскажут как обстоят дела. Но через сутки вопрос закрывают. 39 просмотров всего, один ответ объективно ответом не являющийся. В чём причина закрытия? он что, непонятен? не относится к тематике сайта? расплывчат и неконкретен? Комментариев с претензиями к вопросу не было.

Ну и главное -- я бы хотел назначить награду за качественный ответ. Но сделать этого я теперь не могу.

Comment: вопросу не уделили внимания потому, что совершенно непонятно, какого же ответа вы ждете. "да, готов/нет, не готов"? Вполне обоснованный ответ про облака вас не устраивает (asp.net core должен, по идее, занять свою нишу на linux системах, под windows и без него все хорошо было, а для этого нужна поддержка крупных провайдеров - хотел сказать нам автор ответа). Если я сейчас напишу "да, готов" - вы примете это как ответ. Или потребуете обоснования. Если нужно обоснование - то какое именно?

Comment: @PashaPash вопрос был задан ради того чтобы понять реальное состояние дел. Или хотя бы ссылки по которым можно узнать об опыте использования новой технологии. Если сервис может ответить только на вопросы да/нет или скопипастить готовый ответ -- то для меня лично он бесполезен -- и судя по этому обсуждению, я всё больше склоняюсь к этой мысли.

Comment: что значит "реальное состояние дел"? Вот мой личный опыт - на моем проекте asp.net core использовать пока нельзя (не хватает пары вещей + много легаси кода), на соседнем можно (там нет легаси кода, все хорошо). Это реальное состояние дел. Реальнее некуда. Вы посчитаете такой ответ хорошим? Но ведь ваш вопрос подразумевает именно такой, субъективный и ничем не обоснованный ответ.

Comment: ОК, я понял что я тут со своим недо-вопросом не по адресу. Спасибо за уделённое время.

Comment: вопрос хороший, но я бы из него выбросил часть про "насколько готов".  Закрыли вопрос именн из-за нее. Сам по себе вопрос - что не реализовано, что вообще не будет реализовано, и в чем подводные камни - вполне хороший.

Comment: @nzeemin может быть, отредактировать как предлагает PashaPash и переоткрыть?

Answer (score 10):

Если смотреть с точки зрения вопроса - он хорош и интересен, конкурс за такой исследовательский вопрос тоже замечательная идея.

Однако, если мы будем смотреть на вопрос с точки зрения сообщества, он действительно порождает дискуссию, один скажет готов, другой - не готов. Причем оба смогут подобрать аргументы, с которыми оба не согласятся, потом перессорятся и пойдут минусовать друг друга.

Это как с научным подходом, если нельзя методами науки однозначно ответить на вопрос (первичность материи, существование Бога и т.д.) такой вопрос объявляется ненаучным и не рассматривается в рамках науки. Это не значит, что вопрос плохой или задающий его человек плохой. Вопрос хороший и люди их поднимающие одни из самых умных. Просто если эти вопросы допустить в науку - она сама и ее принципы будут разрушены.

В StackOverflow тоже самое - это проект, который уничтожает ряд проблем присущих тематическим форумам как класс. Тут нет дискуссии, тут четкие ответы в форме соревнования, в форме игры. Игру не так сложно сломать и создатели сделали все возможное, чтобы она не ломалась. Вопрос-дискуссия, это один из способов сломать игру и поссорить участников даже не ставя перед такой цели.

Comment: Слушайте, ну это же не бином ньютона даже, вопрос вполне конкретный. Вот для примера на enSO подобный вопрос не вылился в драку: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36422152/is-net-core-1-0-ready-to-be-used-on-a-full-scale-production-site-yet Да и собственно мой вопрос не привёл к тому что все передрались, наоборот -- меня разочаровало то что вопросу не дали шанса вообще, зарубили на корню.

Comment: Да, к сожалению, многие вопросы закрываются довольно поспешно. Вашему вопросу не дали перерасти в дискуссию. Давайте возьмем другого кандидата на закрытие по этому же критерию http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/543469/ - ответ принят и получил голоса, а дискуссия разгорелась. Причем мы с strangeqargo скорее всего каждый день сидим на одном этаже, я даже догадываюсь на каком он проекте, а тем не менее заспорили. Не отвечаем на другие вопросы не помогаем тем, кому помощь нужна, а спорим между собой. Поэтому такие вопросы закрываются, чтобы не делать площадку местом выяснения отношений.

Answer (score 8):

Я во всем согласен с [ответом cheops](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3361/177188).

---

Но еще добавлю, про сам вопрос. Если в вопросе про АВСД, можно это АВСД заменить на все что угодно, то это плохой вопрос.

Примеры:

- "Google -- насколько готов к использованию?"
- "Монитор LG 12423 -- насколько готов к использованию?"
- "Арбузы из Казахстана-- насколько готовы к использованию?"
- "Юникод -- насколько готов к использованию?"
- "Гайка М6 -- насколько готова к использованию?"

И как замечено выше - не может быть объективных ответов не зная четких критериев "готовности".

Постарайтесь задавать более конкретные вопросы.